# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: web3js, ether, javascript, ethers.js

I am fairly new to Ethereum development, I just tried to follow this tutorial but instead of connection to a public blockchain I am trying to connect to my local blockchain instance through MetaMask which is already installed and the local chain is added to it. However, I am facing an issue at the first line of my code during the "require" part. Here is my code below:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
async function connectToMetamask(){
   await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
}
connectToMetamask();
const signer = provider.getSigner();

const ERC20_ABI = [
   "function getAll() public view returns(uint [] memory)",
   "function get(uint position) public view returns(uint)",
   "function add(uint id, string memory activityName, string memory authorName, string memory activityType) public",
   "function length() public view returns(uint)",
]

const address = '0xf0c707dafa300d8bd19bbfed42b86469d50b022f';

const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(address, ERC20_ABI, provider);

const main = async () => {
   const name = await contractInstance.name();
   console.log("name: " , name);
}

main();
```

And the error I am facing is below:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at code.js:1:20`

Can anyone help me with solving this issue? I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yk7nVp5HTCk) tutorial step-by-step but doesn't seem to work for me..

Note: I have already written my own contract and deployed it to my local blockchain and that is where I got all these functions and the address from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching for a while through the internet I found what the issue was and how to solve it.

***The Issue:***

I was trying to run a Node JS code within my browser (which apparently doesn't work, especially if you're using 'require' keyword).

***The Solution:***

To solve this I had to use [browserify](https://browserify.org/).

What browserify does apparently is wrapping your js code into a new js file that can be run within the browser. The usage could be a little confusing, especially for Windows users since after installing browserify in windows the keyword 'browserify' doesn't get recognized in CMD. So here are the steps I did to make my code work:

- Install browserify by using `npm install -g browserify` command
- Navigate to my project's folder with CMD
- Run this command `node .\node_modules\browserify\bin\cmd.js code.js -o bundle.js` instead of `browserify code.js -o bundle.js` because... well Windows. *(Note that the "code.js" should be replaced with the name of your js file)*
- Finally included the newly generated `bundle.js` file instead of my `code.js` in my html file `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` and my code finally ran fine.

Hope this answers this question to anyone else after me and they won't have to look for days to find this simple answer.